# Sed help requred

Tags: sed

I like to find some thing with sed in file that have many occurrence

File As below

```
"xyz": "somename_dsa", some other text,  "xyz": "zcbr53", some other text, "xyz": "zms53",
```

Item needed 
I need text after "xyz" :

Comment: its a complete string or each xyz: is a separate one ?

Comment: I have tried this But didnt give exact result                 cat repoinfo.txt | grep "xyz" | sed 's/.*xyz//'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using  `gnu awk`

```
awk -v RS='"xyz"' 'NR>1 {print $2}' file
"somename_dsa",
"zcbr53",
"zms53",
```

Or just the data

```
awk -v RS='"xyz"' -F\" 'NR>1 {print $2}' file
somename_dsa
zcbr53
zms53
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/"xyz":\s*/!d;s//\n/g;s/^[^\n]*\n//' file
```

Delete any lines that don't have the required string. Replace the required string with a newline and chop off the first entry.

Comment: It seems its working but its showing end string which i don't require "zcbr53", "language": "python", "utc_last_updated": "2014-06-05 06:33:51+00:00", "email_writers": true, "no_public_forks": false,

Answer (score 0):

You may try this,

```
$ cat rr.txt
"xyz": "somename_dsa", some other text,  "xyz": "zcbr53", some other text, "xyz": "zms53"

$ sed -r '/[^"]*"xyz": ([^,]*)/ s//\1 /g' rr.txt
"somename_dsa" "zcbr53" "zms53" 

$ sed -r '/[^"]*"xyz": "([^"]*)"/ s//\1 /g' rr.txt
somename_dsa zcbr53 zms53
```

All the captured texts are separated by spaces.